# WooCommerce Show Payment Gateways for Logged In Customers Only

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, woocommerce

I am setting up an ecommerce site using Wordpress and WooCommerce. We are using the wordpress member accounts to track customer information, and we need a way for logged in members *only* to be able to choose to purchase their cart "on credit", meaning no payment is required to place the order. Basically what I have done is hi-jacked the "Check" option (since we don't need it anywhere else) and renamed it "Credit" since it allows for the functionality we need.

However, I need a way for the "Credit" (check) option to only display if the user is logged in. Is there any way I can just "unhook" this option if the user isn't logged in? This  seems like something that would be easy to do, but I couldn't find anything about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. In the `class-wc-cheque.php` file, the check or "cheque" (crazy brits) option is hooked using   `add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_cheque_gateway' );`. So the solution was simply to add this code to my `functions.php` file:

```
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
     remove_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_cheque_gateway' );
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The original answer to this question (from BWDesign) no longer works due to changes in WooCommerce (at least from WooCommerce 2.1.7 onwards, possibly before). This does the trick now (tested on 2.1.7 and 2.1.8), add it to e.g. your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_available_payment_gateways", "rp_filter_gateways", 9999 );

function rp_filter_gateways($args) {
 if(!is_user_logged_in() && isset($args['cheque'])) {
  unset($args['cheque']);
 }
 return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I will have to give this a try if I am ever brave (read "crazy") enough to update my WooCommerce version.