# WooCommerce Payment Gateway for Logged In users only

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway

I would like logged in users to be able to use 'cheque' payment option.

I found the following relevant thread: [WooCommerce Show Payment Gateways for Logged In Customers Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864738/woocommerce-show-payment-gateways-for-logged-in-customers-only) However, placing the following code in functions.php no longer works for Woocommerce version 2.3.7:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_available_payment_gateways",     "rp_filter_gateways", 9999 );

function rp_filter_gateways($args) {
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && isset($args['cheque'])) {
   unset($args['cheque']);
  }
  return $args;
}
```

Please can someone provide me with an updated solution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` [is still a valid hook](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/3c3fb22fe99b6814770058f35517ed4bc444b71d/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php#L151). The following code has been tested with the latest version of WooCommerce:

```
function rp_filter_gateways( $args ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && isset($args['cheque']) ) {
        unset( $args['cheque'] );
    }
    return $args;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'rp_filter_gateways' );
```

Comment: yes i tried adding that to the wordpress theme's functions.php but it didn't work.

Comment: Incidentally, the add_filter statement needs to precede the function call - knocked my website offline initially until i realised!

Comment: @OliverIshmael, the problem was with `add_filter()`. I have updated my code. This works with the latest version of WC.

Comment: Hello again Mevius, thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately, I still can't get this code to work. You can see what i mean by using the following login information: www.willowgalleryoswestry.org/wp-login.php (user=willowgalleryoswestry password=testing)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean still. I logged in, and there's no cheque option available. It sounds like you haven't activated it in your Admin interface.